# GWT's various async facilities

Tags: java, gwt, asynchronous

In GWT, there are two ways of making asynchronous, server-side calls: the (older) GWT-RPC, and the (newer) RequestFactory. I'm looking through GWT's API docs for the first time, and seeing a construct that is seemingly used everywhere called `GWT.runAsync`.

How does this `GWT.runAsync` relate to GWT-RPC and RequestFactory? Is `GWT.runAsync` simply the GWT-RPC way of doing things? Or can it be applied to both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GWT.runAsync` does not relate to GWT-RPC or RequestFactory. Both GWT-RPC and RequestFactory are asynchronous and cannot be used in a synchronous manner.

Comment: Thanks @Johannes (+1) - then what does `GWT.runAsync` do, and what packages house GWT-RPC and RequestFactory functionality respectively? Thanks again!

Comment: GWT.runAsync is really meant for Code Splitting. More https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.